# PHPSECLIB ssh2 \n not working

Tags: ssh, phpseclib

So i am removing into a old server running a old IBM OS and GUI
when i go to log in I run command:

```
$ssh->write("username\n");
$ssh->write("Passw0rd");
```

However it just outputs

```
Type Your ID    username
Type your Password
```

Its as if the \n never worked.

Comment: Can you post the SSH logs? You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then `echo $ssh->getLog();` after you do `$ssh->read()`

Answer (score 1):

The system is in the most abstract way is a old windows machine. \n works on modern machines but the older windows use \r

Using \r Resolved the issue.